# Какой механизм удаляет переменные, параметры... после выполнения функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, переменные, сборщик-мусора

На сайте [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/garbage-collection) пишется:

> Существует базовое множество достижимых значений, которые не могут быть удалены. Например: локальные переменные и параметры текущей функции, переменные и параметры других функций в текущей цепочке вложенных вызовов, глобальные переменные...

Возникает вопрос: если алгоритм Mark-and-sweep, который сейчас является основным, не очищает локальные переменные после окончания работы функции, то... что тогда очищает?

Пример №1: функция выполняется, все переменные есть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример №2: функция выполнилась, все переменные удалились.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обрати внимание, что удалились не переменные. Удалился Scope - Local, в котором и хранились ссылки на переменные

Comment: @Grundy ага, понял. То есть сами переменные так и остались, просто мы вышли из скоупа функции, и соответственно все локальные переменные также стали не видны/недоступны. Спасибо